# Cannot access certain youtube playlist via API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There are certain youtube playlist that cannot be accessed via the api, for example [RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs)

How are these playlist different from the regular playlist [PLFgquLnL59alW3xmYiWRaoz0oM3H17Lth](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFgquLnL59alW3xmYiWRaoz0oM3H17Lth) which are accessible via the api?

Comment: Why do you state that the first playlist is not accessible via the API? It comes up just fine ... you can call both the playlist.list endpoint (to get details about the list itself) as well as the playlistitems.list endpoint (to see what's on the list). Try, for example, this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs&key={YOUR_API_KEY} ... works great.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.